# Specific URL matching using tab.url.indexOf()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

In my chrome extension, I need to trigger actions when specific URLs are loaded in the browser. I am trying to match the specific URLs using the code below.

In **background.js**:

```
if (tab.url.indexOf('http://www.example.com/') == 0) {
    chrome.windows.create({'url': 'index.html', 'type': 'panel', "width":1024, "height": 90},   
    function(window) {
    });
}
```

It does work, however it is also recognizing everything in the path as the same URL. eg. www.example.com and www.example.com/path/ as the same thing.

How do I get it to differentiate them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp):

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a
>   specified value in a string.

so it is only useful to check whether the argument string is contained in the calling string and, if so, at what position.

If you are looking for an exact match, you can use [`localeCompare()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) like so:

```
if(tab.url.localeCompare('http://www.example.com/') == 0) {
```

or even just:

```
if(tab.url === 'http://www.example.com/') {
```

(see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for more information on comparison operators and the difference between `==` and `===`)

Comment: Why the downvote? If I misunderstood the question, I would appreciate a clarification and would correct my answer.